# Looking for a combobox but not an Android spinner

Tags: java, android, widget

I'm trying to get the same item as Window's combobox in Android java.  I realize there's a spinner but what I need is to display a scrollable list of items that the user can simply select one or more.  The spinner is nice, but it's a totally different beast.

Is there an equivalent?  Because otherwise I guess I would have to create a section of text items, that I would have to build my own scroll function as well as selection.  Hoping to avoid all that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write your own, or find a library.  There is no builtin equivalent.  Luckily it should be easy, you basically just want a recycler view where the adapter keeps track of what items you've clicked on.  That will take care of the scrolling, and the display simplifies to a normal list adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Import third-party library just for little feature is unnecessary, you could try change spinnerMode to **dialog**, then the spinner is scrollable.

[image]

**Edited：**
sorry, I noticed that you need select multiple items, my answer is not suitable. You could create a custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is using library. There a alot library you can use for that problem. Here is the some library you can used:

https://github.com/prsidhu/MultiSelectSpinner

https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner

Or you can follow this tutorial

https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/

Hope it help